# How to make visual studio for mac xaml formatter auto self close tags

Tags: xaml, format, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

for example this code

```
<Button
    Text="Go Back"
    BackgroundColor="#2196F3"
    TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}"
    CornerRadius="5"
    Clicked="OnGoBackClicked"
    Padding="10,5"
    Margin="10,0,10,10"></Button>
```

format to:

```
<Button
    Text="Go Back"
    BackgroundColor="#2196F3"
    TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}"
    CornerRadius="5"
    Clicked="OnGoBackClicked"
    Padding="10,5"
    Margin="10,0,10,10" />
```

now when i press ^I (Control + I) it does not do that maybe im missing some setting thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Visual Studio > Preferences in the menu bar.
2. In the Preferences dialog box, navigate to Source Code > Code
   Formatting > XAML.
3. Under the "Formatting Style" section, select "Custom" from the
   drop-down menu.
4. Check the box labeled "Self-closing tags" under the "Markup"
   section.
5. Click "OK" to save the changes.

Comment: It looks like i dont have the XAML option i only have XML document but still inside it does not contain self-closing tags
image of the preferences tab here: https://imgur.com/a/0e18exP